# Syntax for # literal in ms-access hyperlink?

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink

This seems like it ought to be a trivial question, but I'm having a hell of a time finding an answer for this so far...

I have an access database that stores hyperlinks to files on a shared network drive. The link targets are specified as simple file paths (e.g. "G:\directoryname\filename.ext") rather than proper URL's ("http://domain.ext/link").

This works fine in general, but I've recently run into a problem involving file names that contain the "#" character. (It is not an option to change the file names to remove the # characters)

If I try to set up a link to something like "G:\directoryname\ExampleFile#24.pdf", then Access parses the # in the filename as it would generally do when it defines a hyperlink. The resulting target is just ""G:\directoryname\ExampleFile", with the portion of the link following the offending "#" simply being truncated.

Now, obviously if the link target were a regular URL, I would just replace the "#" in the text of the link with "%23" and there would be no issue.

The problem is that, if I do that here, my network file action fails, because unlike when opening a regular URL through a browser, the network doesn't recognize %23 as equivalent to # ( I get an error saying "Unable to open G:\directoryname\ExampleFile %23 24.pdf. Cannot open the specified file.")

Is there a more direct way to have ms-access record the link target with a literal # character included?

Comment: How did you try to set the hyperlink in your table? Just directly entering it in the field?

Comment: The hyperlinks are initially stored via VBA code. The VBA seems like it handles all the characters properly, so the links stored in the table end up showing the intended destinations ("G:\directoryname\ExampleFile#24.pdf"). It's just at the point that I need to navigate to the file by clicking the link through a form or table that the # gets parsed in a troublesome way. I have the same behavior if I edit the hyperlinks manually as I get when they've been defined through the VBA.

Comment: `#` in file hyperlinks has a special meaning, it is interpreted that everything following the # is a sub address. E.g. `file://C:\path\Document.docx#myBookmark` opens Document.docx and tries to jump to the bookmark "myBookmark". But I can't help with your problem.

Comment: The only suggestion I have is to try to copy the filename/location and paste it into the tale using Paste As Hyperlink. Not sure if it will work then but its worth a try.

Comment: Well, I do understand the special meaning :) But the fact that it *has* a special meaning is what has me puzzled why there does not seem to be an easy way to define a literal "#" in this context, as there generally would be in almost any other programming/coding environment. Is it really possible that the architects of Access' link-handling functions did not allow for # literals? I am assuming I have to just be missing something obvious, right?

Comment: @random_answer_guy Thank you for the suggestion. :) I just tried it with no luck, though. :(

Comment: *"The link targets are specified as simple file paths"* - how are you creating hyperlinks from them? Must it be hyperlinks? There are other methods to open specified files than hyperlinks, that don't care about # characters.

Comment: @Andre That's a good question. Hyperlinks have been convenient, since (not directly relevant to the original question) some of the links point to locations on the network, while others point to locations on a Sharepoint site (this arrangement is out of my control). I can say that using hyperlinks has been the simplest approach, and it has worked fine *until now*. After running into this issue, you are right, it may be time to redesign in some way using a different method.

Comment: Perhaps in a new table try this. Instead of calling the field a hyperlink field, just set it as `Text`. When entering the link in the Text field surround it with `#` like so `#https://www.google.com#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this certainly doesn't help you but here is your answer:

"You cannot use a pound character in a file name for a hyperlink in an Office program"

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/202261

Comment: That does indeed appear to be the answer. :) Thank you again for your help!